# How do I get my base url to change in Vue/Cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, base-url

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './src/pages/home/Homepage.vue',
  pages: {
    'Home': {
      entry: 'src/pages/home/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Home page',
      chunks: [ 'chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'Home' ]
    },
    'Map': {
      entry: 'src/pages/map/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Map page',
      chunks: [ 'chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'Map' ]
    }
  }
}
```

My app can't seem to get my home page. Am I using the public path correctly? For reference, this is a multipage app. I'm not sure what I should set my base url to since this is the first time I've made anything with Vue. I'm using Vue/Cli. It runs, but says it cannot get my linked page. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`publicPath` is for deployment only - it is not path to your (DEV) file system but path following the domain name when the app is deployed.

[Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

> By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. `https://www.my-app.com/`. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at `https://www.foobar.com/my-app/`, set `publicPath` to `'/my-app/'`

Comment: So how do I get my application to run during development stage? I'm trying to make sure I linked my pages together correctly.

Comment: `publicPath` is not really about `linking your pages together`. During development your site is probably only one running on the dev server so `/` as `publicPath` just works. If you run on subdomain in production, just set it up as documentation describes...

Comment: I see what you're talking about there. Now I'm at a standstill of it rendering a blank page for me, but calling the correct name of the page. So I think I have a new issue and am not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: Maybe problem in configuration. You are using MPA mode so each page should have its  own `html` file after the build. Try to set [filename option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) (different for every page)

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. I'll fix that.